# Looking for pair in a list of playing cards

Tags: python, list, playing-cards

So I am creating a card game in python. For the part of the game I an currently working on, I need to check an array of playing cards to see if there are any pairs. A pair is considered two cards with the same value and color. For example, king of hearts and king of diamonds are a pair, but king of hearts and king of clubs aren't.

I need to return a new list with all of the pairs removed.

Suppose we have

```
list = ['9♠', '5♠', 'K♢', 'A♣', 'K♣', 'K♡', '2♠', 'Q♠', 'K♠', 'Q♢', 'J♠', 'A♡', '4♣', '5♣', '7♡', 'A♠', '10♣', 'Q♡', '8♡', '9♢', '10♢', 'J♡', '10♡', 'J♣', '3♡']
```

The result should be:

```
list without pairs = ['10♣', '2♠', '3♡', '4♣', '7♡', '8♡', '9♠', '9♢', 'A♣', 'A♡', 'A♠', 'J♠', 'J♡', 'J♣', 'K♢', 'K♣', 'K♡', 'K♠', 'Q♠']
```

I currently have this code:

```
import random
result=[]

for i in range(len(l)):
    if '♣' in l[i]:
        pass
    elif '♠' in l[i]:
        pass
    elif '♡' in l[i]:
        pass
    elif '♢' in l[i]:
        pass

random.shuffle(result)
return result
```

Comment: First can you write a function that checks if two card are in the same pair?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. If you really don't have any idea where to start, then you don't have a question appropriate for the site. Please try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: Umm...`a new list with all pairs removed`? Why not a list of a set...i.e. `list(set(YOUR_LIST))`?...sets are kind of meant for removing duplicates

Comment: Try to avoid using builtin `list` as your variable name.

Comment: Can you explain why are you removing `9♠` (9 of spade) and `9♢` (9 of diamond) from your output list along with some other non matching pairs? They do not belong to same color so according to your problem statement, they should be in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cards_list = [
    "9♠",
    "5♠",
    "K♢",
    "A♣",
    "K♣",
    "K♡",
    "2♠",
    "Q♠",
    "K♠",
    "Q♢",
    "J♠",
    "A♡",
    "4♣",
    "5♣",
    "7♡",
    "A♠",
    "10♣",
    "Q♡",
    "8♡",
    "9♢",
    "10♢",
    "J♡",
    "10♡",
    "J♣",
    "3♡",
]    

SAME_COLORS = {"♢": "♡", "♡": "♢", "♠": "♣", "♣": "♠"}
    
list_without_pairs = []
for card in cards_list:
    if card[:-1] + SAME_COLORS[card[-1]] in cards_list:
        continue
    else:
        list_without_pairs.append(card)

print(list_without_pairs)
```

Output:

```
['9♠', '2♠', 'Q♠', 'A♡', '4♣', '7♡', '10♣', '8♡', '9♢', 'J♡', '3♡']
```

This work exactly the same but could be a little bit more confuse:

```
list_without_pairs = [card for card in cards_list if card[:-1] + SAME_COLORS[card[-1]] not in cards_list]
```

Comment: Thank you, before I saw this I managed to figure it out myself. My way is 10x longer and more complicated so I will probably implement this instead.